# Unable to alter partition location in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-partitioning

I am trying to change the partition location of my external hive table.

Command that I try to run:

```
ALTER TALBE sl_uploads PARTITION (hivetimestamp='2016-07-26 15:00:00') SET LOCATION '/data/dev/event/uploads/hivetimestamp=2016-07-26 15:00:00'
```

Error I get :

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path
```

My data for a particular partition exists at the path:

```
/data/dev/event/uploads/hivetimestamp=date time/actual_data
```

I think space is creating an issue. But any help on this would be great.

Comment: try escaping the space using \ : SET LOCATION '/data/dev/event/uploads/hivetimestamp=2016-07-26\ 15:00:00'

Comment: No that does not work. It still gives the same error. I had tried that before in order to skip the space character.

Answer (score 0):

your hdfs in  path is right?

add /actual_data/?

Answer (score 0):

Hive is unable to read the full hdfs path due to space in "2016-07-26 15:00:00";
you can use below commands;

```
hive> set part=2016-07-26 15:00:00;
hive>ALTER TALBE sl_uploads PARTITION (hivetimestamp='2016-07-26 15:00:00') SET LOCATION '/data/dev/event/uploads/hivetimestamp=@part';
```

Comment: It sets the part and alters the partition location but when i run the select count(*) from sl_uploads where hivetimestamp='2016-07-26 15:00:00' it does not work.  It gives the error: 

FAILED: SemanticException java.io.FileNotFoundException: File hdfs://data/dev/event/uploads/hivetimestamp=@part does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

First thing i saw that,  you wrote TALBE instead of TABLE.